# Linux replace ^M$ with $ in csv

Tags: linux, csv, line-endings

I have received a csv file from a ftp server which I am ingesting into a table.
While ingesting the file I am receiving the error "File was a truncated file"

The actual reason is the data in a file contains $ and ^M$ in end of the line.
e.g :

ACT_RUN_TM, PROG_RUN_TM, US_HE_DT**^M$**
"CONFIRMED","","3600"**$**

How can I remove these $ and ^M$ from end of the line using linux command.

Comment: What are you _ingesting_ with?

Comment: Comments on answers indicate that "^M$" is only visible with a setting in VI.  The "$" is not part of the actual file but the ^M is.

Answer (score 3):

The ultimately correct solution is to transfer the file from the FTP server in text mode rather than binary mode, which does the appropriate end-of-line conversion for you. Change your download scripts or FTP application configuration to enable text transfers to fix this in future.

Assuming this is a one-shot transfer and you have already downloaded the file and just want to fix it, you can use tr(1) to translate characters. So to remove *all* control-M characters from a file, you can pipe through `tr -d '\r'`. Or if you want to replace them with control-J instead – for example you would do this if the file came from a pre-OSX Mac system — do `tr '\r' '\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

It's odd to see ^M as not-the-last character, but:

> sed -e 's/^M*\$$//g' <badfile >goodfile

Or use "sed -i" to update in-place.
(Note that "^M" is entered on the command line by pressing `CTRL-V CTRL_M`).

**Update:**  It's been established that the question is wrong as the "^M$" are **not** in the file but displayed with VI.  He actually wants to change CRLF pairs to just LF.

> sed -e 's/^M$//g' <badfile >goodfile

Comment: sed command is not able to delete the ^M$ and $ from the end of the line ( Note : ^M$ and $ is only visible when I set :set list in vi editor

Comment: @ArunPadule, it worked just fine for me on my command-line.  Note the "*" between the "^M" and "\$" to match it optionally.  It doesn't have to be visible to work.  Pipe the output of `sed` into `cat -v` to see special characters.

Comment: OH!  Those characters are **not** in your file.  They're just being displayed.  Let me update the answer...

Comment: sed command is not able to delete the ^M$ and $ from the end of the line 

Below is the sample data :

"a","b"^M$
"d","e"$

( Note : ^M$ and $ is only visible when I set :set list in vi editor )

Comment: we also tried replacing carraige return by break using below command s/\r\r\n/<br>/g. But it is also not working.

Comment: The issue is resolved when we open the csv file on window and save it, as it is. And then copy the same file to linux server , then the ^M$ and $ are disappeared from the end of line , even in :set list mode and I am able to ingest the file. But How can I do these on linux server itself. I need to automate the process and dont need to do it manually

Comment: Forget VI.  Use `cat -v` so you know exactly what is in the file versus what some editor displaying.  There shouldn't be two `\r` together, just one, and the `\n` is managed by "sed" as the line separator so isn't available to match.  `s/\r//g`